# How can affine plane extended of projective plane?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

In the book of *Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry* by Greenberg, it is given that

> DEFINITION:  Lines l and m are parallel if they are distinct lines and
> no point is incident with both of them.
>
> DEFINITION: A projective plane is a model of incidence geometry hav­ing
> the elliptic parallel property (any two lines meet) and such that
> every line has at least three distinct points lying on it
> (strengthened In­ cidence Axiom 2).
>
> DEFINITION: An affine plane is a model of incidence geometry hav­ing
> the following Euclidean parallel property:
>
> For all line $l$, and for all points $P$ that are not incident to $l$,
> there exists a unique line $m$ s.t $P$ is incident to $m$ and $m$ and $l$ are
> parallel.
>
> [...] So the idea in extending an affine plane to a projective plane
> is to add enough new "points at infinity" so that all lines parallel
> to any given line will now meet at one such point.

However, by definition two parallel line cannot have a common point which is incident to both, and when we add "new points at infinity" to make all line meet at a single point, we will not have any parallel lines anymore, so we cannot be working in affine geometry anymore.

Moreover, isn't the definition of affine plane same as the parallel postulate of Euclid ?

**Edit:**
In case I misunderstood someting, here is the exact formulation: ($\exists !$ means exits uniquely)

[image]

Comment: ...Yes, when you extend your affine plane, you now have a projective plane instead of an affine plane.

Comment: @EricWofsey Then the word "extend" misused in here because I always understand that word as we are adding new things without spoiling the existing things, whereas in this case, we are transforming the existing geometry to another.

Comment: @EricWofsey By the way, I'm not confusing anything about the affine geometry, right ? : Affine geometry  = Parallel postulate + incidence geometry.

Comment: Would you say that $\mathbb{C}$ is not an extension of $\mathbb{R}$, because it "spoils" the fact that $-1$ has no square root?

Comment: "Affine geometry" and "incidence geometry" have different meanings in different contexts.  I don't know Greenberg's exact definitions.

Comment: @EricWofsey By doing that extension, you are adding something to $\mathbb{R}^n $ that was not there, whereas in this case, any there were parallel lines, but after the extension, there is no parallel line.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, there is an element that has no square root.  In $\mathbb{C}$, there isn't.  How is that any different?  It's not as though the parallel lines stopped existing; they just stopped being parallel, the same way $-1$ stopped having no square root.

Comment: @EricWofsey You made a point, so I withdraw my argument.

Comment: We can read it this way : we add a new *axiom* : the elliptic parallel property, i.e. any two lines meet. This axiom "cut-off" the Euclidean plane, i.e. it is no more a model of the new theory, because it does not satisfy the new axiom. Then we consider a new "environment" : the Euclidean plane with the addition of the new points at infinity : now the above axiom is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when we add "new points at infinity" to make all line meet at a single point, we will not have any parallel lines anymore

True: when you extend the affine plane to a projective one, you have no parallels any more.

> we cannot be working in affine geometry anymore

Essentially yes: the geometry of the projective plane is different from that of the affine plane.

You can however use the projective plane as a model for the affine plane, as long as you keep track of which line is the line at infinity. So for example, the operation “draw parallel to $l$ through $P$” from affine geometry would become “intersect $l$ with the line at infinity, then connect that point of intersection with $P$”. Different vocabulary, but in 1:1 correspondence so both describe the same mathematical structure.

So while you can say that the projective plane is an affine plane with additional points, you can also say that an affine plane is a projective plane with one designated line to serve as the line at infinity. I've discussed this viewpoint before in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1815758/35416).